# How to update specific text in google drive docs with node.js {name}

Tags: node.js, google-docs-api

I'm trying to update a single text like {name} in a google drive docs with google drive API. for example if i have the variable name = 'hello world' inside the document the text {name} should be replaced by 'hello world'. any help is appreciated.

```
async function replaceText() {
  try {
    const id = "144zvxc_xQUuEqKgS5BfjOKMQsfegFI2Vey";
    
    drive.files.update(
      {
        fileId: id,
        requests = [
            {
              replaceAllText: {
                containsText: {
                  text: "{{firstname}}",
                  matchCase: true,
                },
                replaceText: 'hello world',
              },
            },
          ]
      },
    );
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: About `I'm trying to update a single text like {name} in a google drive docs with google drive API.`, unfortunately, there is no `replaceAllText` request in the update method in Drive API. So in this case, how about using Google Docs API? Because `replaceAllText` is for the batchUpdate method in Docs API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest)

Comment: Thank you so much #Tanaike that is exactly what I'm looking for, Unfortunately i was not able to know where I should set those values. Have you any idea or example could be great. again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying of `Have you any idea or example could be great.`, I post an answer for modifying your script using Google Docs API. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to replace `{{firstname}}` with `hello world` on Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Document using Docs API.

Unfortunately, there is no `replaceAllText` request in the update method in Drive API. In this case, please use the method of batchUpdate of Google Docs API. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents`.

```
const docs = google.docs({ version: "v1", auth }); // Please use `auth` of your script.
const documentId = "###"; // Please set your Google Document ID.

const requests = [
  {
    replaceAllText: {
      containsText: {
        text: "{{firstname}}",
        matchCase: true,
      },
      replaceText: "hello world",
    },
  },
];
docs.documents.batchUpdate(
  {
    auth,
    documentId: documentId,
    requestBody: {
      requests,
    },
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(e);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.data);
  }
);
```

- When you want to replace `{name}` with `hello world`, please modify above script from `text: "{{firstname}}",` to `text: "{name}",`.

#### Note:

- **In this modification, it supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Document using Google Docs API. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest)

Comment: You are the best, I didn't know that it was an specific API for google docs, i was thinking that the API for google drive was the responsible to replace the text.  You have saved my life, thank you so much for your support.